# Почему пишет отказано в доступе?

Tags: java

Добрый день, при попытке выгрузить из ресурсов в системный диск C:\

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("scr/resources/sp/Sp.exe"); 
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("C:/SP");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;

while ((count=din.read(buffer)) != -1){ 
    outF.write(buffer,0,count);
}
outF.flush();
outF.close();
```

в созданную папку выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\SP (Отказано в доступе)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at com4j_example.Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

и так с любым местом выгрузки.

Comment: у вас нет прав на запись в эту директорию. Если вы попытаетесь записать в C:\Users\<your user>\ , то у вас должно получиться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Иногда такое происходит, когда вы пытаетесь писать в папку, а не в файл. Особенно C:/SP, без расширения файла похоже на папку. Проверьте, не имеет ли место быть эта ситуация и отпишитесь.

Comment: Да точно всё правильно забыл дописать имя и расширение файла, но теперь выдаёт  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
 at com4j_example.Main.main(Main.java:94)

Comment: Посмотрите, что возвращает Main.class.getResourceAsStream, если он даёт null, то в DataInputStream тоже попадает null, отсюда и исключение. Если я прав, то вам нужно разобраться, правильно ли вы прописываете путь к файлу и используете getResourceAsStream (к сожалению, никогда с ней не работал, поэтому не буду пытаться угадать проблему сходу)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> new FileOutputStream("C:/SP");
> ```

Windows запрещает запись в корень системного диска без админских прав.

А ещё подозрения вызывает направление слешей.

Comment: Всё в порядке со слешами иначе среда разработки ругается)